# Create a Sales Rank table for the products sold based on the quantity sold

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have sales data in BQ which contains following columns -

```
Customer Id | ItemID | Order_Qty | Order_Date
```

I want to create a sales rank table based on total quantity sold for an item.

Highest rank for the maximum number of items sold.

Eg. - Item abc with total 30 quantities sold should be ranked 1, Item XYZ with total 20 quantities sold should be ranked 2 and so on so forth.

In my resulting table, I want following columns.

```
ItemId | Total Quantity | Rank
```

Here is my attempt so far in legacy SQL format-

```
select ItemId ,
       RANK() over (partition by ItemId order by Qty desc) as salesrank
from (SELECT ItemId, sum(order_qty) as Qty
      FROM sales
      group by 1
     )
```

For some reason all the sales rank is 1

Comment: Your query should fail, because `itemId` is not in the subquery.

Comment: I just edited the query. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  ItemID, Total_Quantity, 
  RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Total_Quantity DESC) AS rnk
FROM (
  SELECT ItemID, SUM(Order_Qty) AS Total_Quantity
  FROM sales
  GROUP BY ItemID
)
-- ORDER BY rnk
```

Answer (score 0):

I am speculating that you want the rank by `ean`.  If so:

```
SELECT ean, SUM(order_qty) as Qty,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(order_qty) DESC) as rnk
FROM sales
GROUP BY ean;
```

In legacy SQL, this might be:

```
SELECT ean, SUM(order_qty) as Qty,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY qty DESC) as rnk
FROM sales
GROUP BY ean
```

Comment: I tried this query already but it's failing. In BQ it throws the error - In analytic expression, ORDER BY must refer to named columns. Found SUM